# Find the desired point using Lagrange's Multiplier Method

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the point on the line intersection of the two planes $2x+y+z=4$ and $x+2y-z=2$ which is closet to the $z$-axis.

Using it by conventional approach is fine but how can we do it with the help of Lagrange's Multiplier Method?

Comment: Do you know how do use Lagrange Multipliers with 2 constraints?

Comment: Till now I have only gone through single constraint.

Comment: It is a straightforward generalization, just introduce to Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ that take into account the two constraints in the Lagrangian (which contains also the function to minimise -distance to z axis) and derive wrt $x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.

Comment: @amd it depends on how you write the condition: if you add a term $\lambda_1 (2x+y+z-4)$ in your Lagrangian, you can take partial derivatives wrt to $\lambda_1$ as well and set it equal zero to simply recover the constraint..that's what I meant..